# Installing duplicity via the ppa fails

Tags: 16.04, ppa, duplicity

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001518354-How-to-configure-Backblaze-B2-with-Duplicity-on-Linux) for setting up duplicity on ubuntu 16.04 server. but:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:duplicity-team/ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~duplicity-team/ubuntu/ppa'.
The team named '~duplicity-team' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/ppa'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'duplicity-develop-git':  duplicity-develop-git
 * 'duplicity-release-git':  duplicity-release-git
```

I try following the suggestion:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:duplicity-release-git/ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~duplicity-release-git/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~duplicity-release-git' user or team does not exist.
```

How can I install 0.7.12 or newer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik there is no ppa maintained for Xenial Xyrus 16.04 anymore.

current duplicity is 0.8.15 and install options are mentioned below (from the release notes). **note:** the ppa repos are for "recent" ubuntus only. also beware of the note to UNINSTALL other versions before installing a recent duplicity.

> - Source - https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity
> - Stable tarball install - https://launchpad.net/duplicity/+download
> - Daily duplicity PPA -    [https://code.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git)
> - Stable duplicity PPA -    [https://code.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-release-git](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-release-git)
>   [https://code.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git)
> - Stable snap builds - “sudo snap install duplicity —classic"
> - Latest snap builds - “sudo snap install duplicity —classic —edge"
> - Latest pip3 builds - “sudo pip3 install duplicity"
>
> NOTE: UNinstall duplicity first if it was installed via the distribution
> repository.  For Ubuntu, that would be "sudo apt-get purge duplicity".